# helm post-upgrade hook running before all pods upgraded

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am very confused by helm post-upgrade hook. The documentation says: Executes on an upgrade request after all resources have been upgraded.

But I am seeing that hook starts even when all the pods in the deployment are not yet updated.

I created and upgraded a chart and the hook is running almost the same time the first pod starts. Here are timestamps for the chart:

**Test 1:**
**Pre-upgrade hook**
Started: Tue, 25 Oct 2022 15:51:29 +0530
Finished: Tue, 25 Oct 2022 15:51:41 +0530

**Post-upgrade hook**
Started: Tue, 25 Oct 2022 15:51:46 +0530
Finished: Tue, 25 Oct 2022 15:51:58 +0530

**Pod 2**
Started: Tue, 25 Oct 2022 15:52:10 +0530

**Pod 1**
Started: Tue, 25 Oct 2022 15:52:15 +0530

**Pod 0**
Started: Tue, 25 Oct 2022 15:52:20 +0530

**Test 2:**
**Post-upgrade hook**
Started: Tue, 25 Oct 2022 16:03:50 +0530

**Pod 2**
Started: Tue, 25 Oct 2022 16:03:54 +0530

**Pod 1**
Started: Tue, 25 Oct 2022 16:04:00 +0530

**Pod 0**
Started: Tue, 25 Oct 2022 16:04:05 +0530

As we can see in below image, the hook goes into container-creating state even as main pods are in terminating/container-creating state.
[image]

helm itself says it is in "pending-upgrade" state.
[image]

What am I missing here? How do I run a pod once all the replicas have been updated to newer image? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Executes on an upgrade request after all resources have been upgraded.

A kubernetes deployment can be "upgraded" and return before all the pods have been cycled. This does sound like the situation you are running into here. Are you using `--wait` as part of your helm install/upgrade?